# Android reading text file from URL and setting arraylist

Tags: android, url, networking, text-files

I want to read a text file from a URL, parse, and then set an arraylist and then add it to my adapter. However whenever I try launching the app I'm finding my infos arraylist is not populating with data. I want to know how do I get the application to read data from a URL and then display it. I do have the persmission for INTERNET in the maniifest.

```
 CardAdapter ca = new CardAdapter(createList(0));

    recList.setAdapter(ca);

    ArrayList<CardInfo> infos = new ArrayList<CardInfo>();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56230108/events.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("value", line);
            String[] a = line.split("\\$EV\\$");
            CardInfo info = new CardInfo();
            info.title = a[0];
            info.desc = a[1];
            info.date = a[2];
            info.time = a[3];
            info.contact = a[4];
            infos.add(info);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    if(infos.size() > 0)
    {
        ca.add(infos.get(0), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only ever adding a single item to your adapter. Try this for loop instead of the if statement you have, at the bottom of your code:

```
for(CardInfo info: infos)
{
    ca.add(info, 0);
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I cannot even read the URL, I am not getting any data input

Answer (score 0):

you forgot use `URLConnection` to connect to link.

Comment: try to improve the answer with relevant code example. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer